# Flagged posts responded to by people with very low reputation

Tags: support, bug, flagging

I'm curious to know how some posts I flagged were seemingly reviewed by users with reputation lower than mine.  I can't review flagged posts, yet I have a higher reputation.  Seems like a bug?

Here are a couple of users who reviewed my recent flags:

[image: Flags - reviewed by users with low reputation]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the content of the screenshot.

We don't show you who handled the flags you raised. The "answered 22 hours ago by Sandip Pal" text is the information about when the answer you flagged as not an answer was written and by whom. This contrasts with questions which read "asked [time period] ago by [username]" there are some examples of this on [your spam flags list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/57090?group=2).

Not an answer flags are marked helpful when a moderator handles the flag and marks it helpful (which is what happened in this case) or when sufficient users review the answer as "recommend deletion" or "delete" in the [Low Quality Posts review queue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Catija, yes I did misunderstand the names in my screenshot - I see now that Sandip posted an Answer, which has since been deleted through moderator intervention.  He doesn't have any other posts, which added to my bewilderment.